# Is Black Mirror Series 5 epsiode 3, a dark extension of Hannah Montana?

Tags: black-mirror, hannah-montana

In *Black Mirror* S05E03 aka *Rachel, Jack and Ashley Too*, Miley Cyrus again played a character of popstar who need to maintain her cover-up persona for fans.

It got so much parallel to Hannah Montana story too but in more darkish ways. Also in Hannah Montana, there was a specific episode where Miley try a different genre like the episode end and it didn't work with her label and episode ends with her performing her new track which was not like her other songs.

It made me wonder if there any inspiration involved here. Is Black MIrror inspired by Hannah Montana? Looking for official proof, not speculation.

Comment: If it smells like cake, taste like cake, look like a cake and the baker is well known for making cakes then yes, you can assume it's a cake. Official proof would be Charlie Brooker saying that Cyrus took the role to "piss people off".

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY but there are also claims that's it's about JoJo Siwa

Comment: I wasn't aware that JoJo tried to fight with her nice girl persona and made risky decision toward making songs that would offend people.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Jojo Siwa tried to sell her hair bow as a mean to be a friend like Ashley 2 and there is a conspiracy that her personality is fake. Also this article https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/tv/a27757252/miley-cyrus-black-mirror-episode/